# CSS inheritance: How to override inherited values

Tags: css, inheritance, colors, nested

I'm supposed to make some changes to a wordpress template. One of them is to change the background color of an element to transparent. The wrapper div, which has the background-color attached to it, has a big amount of nested child divs that all inherit that color.

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">
                 ....


.A {
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

I assumed just changing the parents color would lead to the children inheriting that change. But while overwriting the parents color works, the children still inherit the original color. Since these nestings are ridiculously deep, I don't want to change it for each and everyone of them.

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Edit: To make it clearer: This is the parent. As you can see, the background-color atrribute has been overwritten by me.

[image: Parent overwritten]

And this is a child wrapper. It still inherits that value, even if it has been overwritten

[image: Child still inheriting]

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, nope, if any ancestor has color (lets say red) and any of it's children has background color transparent... that would mean that the child background will "appear" to be red, it'll just be showing the red color of the ancestor

Comment: which are the ' original ' styles to the parent ( A ) element ?

Comment: I edited my post and added screenshots to it, to make the issue clearer

Comment: FYI: This is _not_ inheritance, not in the way that word is used in CSS context.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. What is it that I'm talking about in this context? For future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and I thought this might help others.

Adding an asterix to my parent element did the trick:

```
.A * {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

This way the change in the parent element is picked up by the nested children aswell.

Comment: `*` selector is a general descendant selector. So you do not change the parent styles, you add that style to all  of it's descendants . BUT NOT to the parent element. So here is not about inheritance it's about adding a style to all elements inside that element.